# Windows Phone 8 AdControl not showing on my Device

Tags: windows-phone-8, ads

I am building windows phone 8 Html 5 application, since my computer does not have capability to show emulator I am testing on real device.

My code is like below, when I launch my application, I do not see anything about banner, however I cannot tap on the place where ad is coming (For example I cannot click top header of browser because I know banner is there but totally transparent - not visible)

Is there any idea why it is happening?

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Loaded="Browser_Loaded"
                          NavigationFailed="Browser_NavigationFailed" />

        <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="test_client" 
                      AdUnitId="Image480_80" Margin="0,0,10,600" />
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that it's working but there wasn't an ad available when you ran it. Add an event handler to the ErrorOccurred event and see if it gets hit. If ErrorOccurred get's hit, you should be able to look at what the error was. Most likely it will just be that there isn't an ad to show.

It's happened to me a few times, but it was just the fact that there's more ad's being requested to be shown than there are ad's to fill the spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found out I need to set width and height properties explicitly on the control then it works. Thanks.

Comment: how implement this using C#. i'm working in a html app ?

Comment: @Teomanshipahi what do you mean by setting the width and height explicitly? coz i'm facing the same problem now?

Comment: You need to give width and height properties of UI:AdControl.